# Path traversal vulnerability

Tags: asp.net, path-traversal

The concept of path traversal is new to me need some guidance please.

In my project I have following line of code:

```
uploadimg.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("tempfiles/" + fUIName));
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("tempfiles/" + fSIName));
```

Is this code is vulnerable to `PathTraversal` vulnerability.

Can any one help me understanding the concept of path traversal and how to remove/avoid it.
Thanks!

Edit 1:

It is also mentioned that I am storing files in `tempfiles` folder temporary. After the purpose of saving the file fulfilled I am deleting the files from `tempfiles`. So can I skip this vulnerability?
Please guide.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The path traversal **is means that some one upload a file to your site and can access it direct from the URL** (if he knows the path, or can find it from some other page).

Eg, lets say that you upload a pdf file named `file.pdf` at `tempfiles/`

Then you probably show it on some page as `http://example.com/tempfiles/file.pdf`

Now the attacker knows where the file is uploaded, and then its upload to you some other file, maybe an `html with fraud`, maybe some `server browser` in an aspx page etc... and direct call it from the url.

### Solutions

You **can upload all the files to a secure folder** like `App_Data` that you can not direct access it.

You can upload it to a **folder that you change the permissions** and again you can not direct access it. (see here how you can do that [How to set correct file permissions for ASP.NET on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677887/how-to-set-correct-file-permissions-for-asp-net-on-iis/16678016#16678016))

You can limit the extensions for what you upload and let only images for example, and put that on that directory to avoid anyone to run anything there.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now, if you upload pdf to a directory that the user can not access direct from the url, you need to create a **handler that return the uploaded files**. The handler must knows if the user is allowed to view the file, if the file is safe, if the file come direct from the site.

some simple examples.
[file download by calling .ashx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087040/file-download-by-calling-ashx-page/12087222#12087222) and [Alternate image display in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100618/alternate-image-display-in-asp-net/14100791#14100791)

And one last solution is to check the reference and make sure that is comming from your site and its not a direct call from the url using this `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Host`. Meaning that the user is uploading an image, but its allowed to view it only if its come the request from a page of your site using some link.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added some additional information in my question. Can you please clarify the same ?

Comment: @AmitKaushal I think I have answer to that - if you delete it after the save, then just make that folder private to not been able to read by the users - the most easy way is to make a temp folder inside the App_Data folder

Comment: Will the canonical path serves the purpose?